# String list in GLib/GTK2

Tags: c, gtk, glib

How to work with list of strings in GLib/GTK2? Before I worked with QStringList in Qt library and now lookup how to do the same things in GLib/GTK2. I know that there are GList and GString datatypes. But I don't understand how to properly works with it. Unsure trying to google with keywords 'glib gstring glist' doesn't help me. I can't find good tutorial.

In really I need now some basics functional. Create list, fill with strings in loop, check that list contains a some string and clear list. That's all.

In Qt I can do

```
QStringList list;
list << "first" << "second" << "third";
for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); ++i) {
    QString str = list.at(i);
    if (str == "second") {
        doSomeActions();
    }
}
list.clear();
```

Which analogue in GLib? In real application strings will be allocated dynamically. So in `clear()` all pointers must be freed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Gnome developer documentation gives answers to all your questions. For GList, there are already examples given in the descriptions.

https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.56/glib-Doubly-Linked-Lists.html

https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.56/glib-Strings.html

Since you're not really asking a specific question, I can't give you a specific answer. Feel free to ask again if something is unclear after reading and trying out the given resources.

The QT snippet with GList would look something like this (with dynamic allocation):

```
GList *list = NULL;

g_list_append(list, g_strdup("first"));
g_list_append(list, g_strdup("second"));
g_list_append(list, g_strdup("third"));
for (GList *l = list; l != NULL; l = l->next) {
    if (g_strcmp(l->data, "second") == 0) {
        doSomeActions();
    }
}

g_list_free_full(list, g_free);
```

Comment: "Since you're not really asking a specific question, I can't give you a specific answer." -- Right. This should be a comment, not an answer; but the OP question is too broad anyway.

Comment: Update question.

Comment: I think in the end must be `list = NULL;` to allow reuse list without extra actions.